# Why does iostream include time.h?

Tags: c++, namespaces, compiler-errors, std

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class C>
struct time { };

int main() { }
```

It produces (GCC 4.5):

```
error: ‘template<class C> struct time’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
/usr/include/time.h:186:15: error: previous declaration of ‘time_t time(time_t*)’
```

1. Why does `iostream` include `time_t time(time_t*)` ?
2. Why does `iostream` include `time_t time(time_t*)` outside `std` namespace?
3. (unanswered) **Why, if I remove `template<class C>`, do I not get this error?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run `g++ -H -Wall -c testim.cc` (where `testim.cc` is your example) you'll see that

```
.... /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ios_base.h
..... /usr/include/c++/4.6/ext/atomicity.h
...... /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/gthr.h
....... /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/gthr-default.h
........ /usr/include/pthread.h
......... /usr/include/sched.h
.......... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include/stddef.h
.......... /usr/include/time.h
```

So `<time.h>` is included for pthread support.

This is with GCC 4.6 on Debian/Sid/AMD64

Comment: Try it on 4.6.2. The changelog says that dependence on `<cstddef>` has been reduced.

Comment: On my machine g++ is `gcc version 4.6.2 (Debian 4.6.2-3)`

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be for locale support on my box:

```
$ cat whytime.cc 
#define _TIME_H_
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "hello, world" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

$ g++ -Wall -Werror -Wextra -ansi -o whytime whytime.cc && ./whytime
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cwchar:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/postypes.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:49,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream:45,
                 from whytime.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ctime:66: error: ‘::clock_t’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ctime:68: error: ‘::tm’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ctime:70: error: ‘::clock’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ctime:71: error: ‘::difftime’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ctime:72: error: ‘::mktime’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ctime:73: error: ‘::time’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ctime:74: error: ‘::asctime’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ctime:75: error: ‘::ctime’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ctime:76: error: ‘::gmtime’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ctime:77: error: ‘::localtime’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ctime:78: error: ‘::strftime’ has not been declared
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/locale:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ostream.tcc:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:572,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream:45,
                 from whytime.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc: In member function ‘_InIter std::time_get<_CharT, _InIter>::_M_extract_via_format(_InIter, _InIter, std::ios_base&, std::_Ios_Iostate&, tm*, const _CharT*) const’:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:1839: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:1846: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:1854: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:1861: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:1873: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:1880: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:1883: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:1895: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:1900: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:1908: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:1912: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:1932: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:1968: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:1976: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc: In member function ‘virtual _InIter std::time_get<_CharT, _InIter>::do_get_weekday(_InIter, _InIter, std::ios_base&, std::_Ios_Iostate&, tm*) const’:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:2210: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc: In member function ‘virtual _InIter std::time_get<_CharT, _InIter>::do_get_monthname(_InIter, _InIter, std::ios_base&, std::_Ios_Iostate&, tm*) const’:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:2259: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc: In member function ‘virtual _InIter std::time_get<_CharT, _InIter>::do_get_year(_InIter, _InIter, std::ios_base&, std::_Ios_Iostate&, tm*) const’:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.tcc:2288: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct tm’
/usr/include/wchar.h:152: error: forward declaration of ‘struct tm’
```

Comment: By defining `time.h`'s header guard, we force its inclusion to do nothing.  Presumably whatever includes it will also use it soon after, and the resulting compile errors will catch the includer red-handed.  For me, that seems to be `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/locale` brought in by `ostream`.  One should remember that this only shows one includer, there may be others.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently GCC's `iostream` needs something in `time` for something.

`time_t` is a `C` language thing, which doesn't have namespaces, and so for backwards comparability-ish, it is in both the `std` namespace, and not in the `std` namespace.

As for why there's no errors, I'm not 100% sure.  I know `C` could have functions and structs with the same name, and `struct`s were qualified with the name `struct` so that the compiler could tell them apart.  C++ compilers thinks it's a function, unless preceeded with the `struct` keyword.   http://ideone.com/XZB2M v http://ideone.com/kWMKE.  I guess it also allows that for backwards comparability?

Comment: phs says it includes `ctime` for locale support, which kinda makes sense.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea about that one.  Sorry :(