# Is there anything called time in iostream or somewhere else in C++?

Tags: c++, time, iostream, standard-library, std

The codes compiles without error, but `time` is declared nowhere.

Fortunately, the error has been gone as I changed the name as mtime. But what is the nature of the error is? What is `time`?

The output of this program is `1`. I wonder if there is anything called `time` in the file `iostream` or somewhere.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << time << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably the [`std::time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) function, or rather its C-equivalent [`time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time). A pointer to a function will be seen as a boolean value that is always true, and `true` will without manipulators or setting flags in `std::cout` be printed as `1`.

Comment: What is you platform and what is your compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the address of a `time_t time(time_t*)` function as your `<iostream>` implementation includes the `time.h` header. The address [will never be NULL](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/215af9bea3ab485f) and is implicitly convertible to boolean hence the result of `1`. You are probably using g++ on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

My suspect is that it's the `time_t time(time*)` function, whose `operator<<` best match is the one taking a `bool` (a function pointer is just an implicit conversion away from a `bool`). Now, given that it's a function pointer pointing to an actual valid function, it is converted as `true`, which is then printed as `1` (the default if the `boolalpha` flag is not set is to print booleans as 0/1).

Answer (score 0):

There is [`std::time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time), but that shouldn't be the case, since `std` is not the namespace used.

So, it has to be this [function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/):

> time_t time (time_t* timer);

which has to be included implicitly by `iostream` header.

Answer (score 0):

C++ standard library functions are defined in namespace `std`. For instance,  `<ctime>` header is required to provide `std::time` function. But in practice this functionality is provided by underlying C library where there is no concept of namespaces. So, C++ standard library headers are allowed to also define certain functions in global namespace.

A quote from [C compatibility headers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header#C_compatibility_headers) section in cppreference:

> including `<cstdlib>` definitely provides `std::malloc` and may also provide ::malloc. Including `<stdlib.h>` definitely provides `::malloc` and may also provide `std::malloc`.

So, for instance, `time` function may happen to be defined in global namespace after a standard library header is included. This is allowed by standard but is implementation specific.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a question [Why does iostream include time.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016646/why-does-iostream-include-time-h) verifying the answers above and explaining the reason for the function's appearing.
It's really the work of function `time_t time(time_t * timer)` :）