# source is compiled without proper #include

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, time.h, ctime

I have a very simple c++ source like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
}
```

I am using g++ to compile like this :

```
g++ ./test.cpp
```

but it successfully compiles despite the fact that `time()` function is defined in `ctime` and it is not included with `#include`

my professor at university runs the code with visual studio (vc++) but he is unable to run the code without including  `ctime`

Am I missing something here ?

by the way my g++ version is :

`g++ (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2) 11.2.0`

Comment: Standard headers are allowed to include other standard headers. Don't rely on this. Always include headers you need

Comment: on a side note for C++ random, have a look at the <random> header file. (srand is IMO a bit of a "C" left over)

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes.final conclusion is exactly what you said.but it can be misleading for a new c++ programmer!

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes you are right . actually this c++ code is translated from a c counterpart !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, on my platform, it **didn't** compile successfully when I removed `#include <iostream>`
I am using WSL2 ubuntu 20.04, compiler i used g++ and clang++.
Whichever compiler it is, it gives the error:

```sh
>>> g++ t.cpp
t.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cpp:2:16: error: ‘NULL’ was not declared in this scope
    2 |     srand(time(NULL));
      |                ^~~~
t.cpp:1:1: note: ‘NULL’ is defined in header ‘<cstddef>’; did you forget to ‘#include <cstddef>’?
  +++ |+#include <cstddef>
    1 | int main() {
t.cpp:2:11: error: ‘time’ was not declared in this scope
    2 |     srand(time(NULL));
      |           ^~~~
t.cpp:2:5: error: ‘srand’ was not declared in this scope
    2 |     srand(time(NULL));
      |     ^~~~~
>>>clang t.cpp
t.cpp:2:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NULL'
    srand(time(NULL));
               ^
1 error generated.
```

I think you can use the compile option -E to prompt the compiler to do only preprocessing and to see the preprocessed file.
like this:
`g++ t.cpp -E -o pre_proccessed.cpp`
Determine whether the compiler did what you suspect it did during the compilation process, "automatically include the file"

But, when I add `#include <iostream>`
It did success.
So, I did this:

```sh
>>>g++ t.cpp -E  -o t_.cpp
>>>cat t_.cpp | grep srand
extern void srandom (unsigned int __seed) throw ();
extern int srandom_r (unsigned int __seed, struct random_data *__buf)
extern void srand (unsigned int __seed) throw ();
extern void srand48 (long int __seedval) throw ();
extern int srand48_r (long int __seedval, struct drand48_data *__buffer)
  using ::srand;
```

This explains why its compilation succeeded, because the iostream file included in this platform has the definition of this function in it.
In addition, look at this [problam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016646/why-does-iostream-include-time-h)

In fact, stl are allowed to include each other.
But even though it is defined in this header file, you cannot rely on it, some versions of the iostream implementation do not include this.

What you should do is to actively include the `cstdlib` file when using `srand`, don't worry about the multiple inclusion problem, std,stl itself can handle multiple inclusion very well, and modern compilers can also handle this problem very well.

Comment: Actually I have checked now `srand()` is defined in `stdlib.h` and `NULL` is defined in `stddef.h`. despite those are not included too my code compiles!!!!

Comment: @MohamadrezaNakhleh see answer update.

Comment: I compiled with -E and here is the result https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uhvt4SULE5F-XKyTRKBNHXiCbh48cn1b/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @MohamadrezaNakhleh use `cat` command to see what in that file and use `| grep srand` to verify if srand is include in this file.

Comment: OK, it seems you are right!
`
extern void srandom (unsigned int __seed) noexcept (true);
extern int srandom_r (unsigned int __seed, struct random_data *__buf)
extern void srand (unsigned int __seed) noexcept (true);
extern void srand48 (long int __seedval) noexcept (true);
extern int srand48_r (long int __seedval, struct drand48_data *__buffer)
  using ::srand;
    srand(time(`
now i understand.thanks

Answer (score 0):

first of all explicitly include what you need,
(thanks to darkblueflow for pointing it out)
secondly
`#include` order matters,

believe or not they can shadow declaration,
just switch if first case doesn't work

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

// differs from

#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

// in some aspects
```

your best shot is to include headers explicitly
and keep this in mind
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762568/c-c-include-header-file-order#:%7E:text=As%20of%20now%2C%20Google%20C%2B%2B,first%2C%20following%20Lakos%27%20suggestion.&text=You%20don%27t%20get%20much,a%20lot%20of%20system%20dependencies.)
good luck